# clip path selection Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

The below selector will not find `<clipPath>` elements inside `<defs>` on Chrome (38):

```
d3.selectAll('defs clipPath')
```

(This is D3.js code but I suspect underlying `querySelectorAll` issue)

It works fine on Firefox. Is there a different selector syntax to use that will work on both browsers?

In the example below on Firefox you will see the whole text because the clip path is removed. But on Chrome it will be cut off after 85 pixels because the clip path is not removed.

```js
d3.selectAll('defs clipPath').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg height="200" width="400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip1">
      <rect id='tt' x="0" y="0" width="85" height="15"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <text clip-path="url(#clip1)" x="0" y="15">This text should all be visible once we remove the clip-path</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438). Assign an ID or class to select by instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lars pointed out, this was a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438), and now in Blink it still exists as [Issue 237435: querySelectorAll unable to find SVG camelCase elements in HTML](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237435)

So until it's fixed, using a class selector is probably the best workaround.

```
d3.selectAll('defs .clippy').remove();
```

```js
d3.selectAll('defs .clippy').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg height="200" width="400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip1" class='clippy'>
      <rect id='tt' x="0" y="0" width="85" height="15"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <text clip-path="url(#clip1)" x="0" y="15">This text should all be visible once we remove the clip-path</text>
</svg>
```